# Map is only displaying one item in it

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display the items in the array, but only one item is being displayed. I have tried changing id, although it didnt work.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Note from './noteItself';
const NoteItems=[
    {id:1, message:'asdf',title:'New Note'},
    {id:2, message:'asdf',title:'e'}
]
const NoteDisplay = () => {

    return (
        <div className="note-container">
            {NoteItems.map((items)=><Note items={items}/>)}
        </div>
    )

}
export default NoteDisplay;
```

```
import React from 'react';

const Note = ({items}) => {
    console.log(items);
    return (
        
        <div className="note-box">
            <h1 className="note-title">{items.title}</h1>
        </div>
    )

}
export default Note;
```

#### css

```css
.note-container { display: flex; }
.note-box { flex-direction: row; flex-grow: 1; height: 181px; width: 181px; border-radius: 20px; position: absolute; left: 22.09%; right: 65.94%; top: 26.58%; bottom: 54.99%; background: #ffffff; box-shadow: 0px 3px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09); border-radius: 20px; }
```

Comment: I can honestly think of no reason why that's happening.

Comment: I just took a look, it is because each item is not shifting when being displayed, like item one is displayed under item 2. Is there a way in css to fix this? flexbox? im kind of new to this

Comment: can you add two css classes as well?

Comment: not sure what you mean by that

Comment: content of `note-container` and `note-box`

Comment: `
.note-container {
  display: flex;
}
.note-box {
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 181px;
  width: 181px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 22.09%;
  right: 65.94%;
  top: 26.58%;
  bottom: 54.99%;

  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
  border-radius: 20px;
}
`
not sure how to format

Comment: You need to add `flex-direction: column` to your `.note-container` class. Also using absolute positioning for a flex item may not be useful because now it will no longer be part of the flex box

Comment: it works, but how do i get it back to the position it was before? now it is in the top right corner

Comment: If you want the items to display in a column (i.e. one per row), you need to remove `position: absolute` from the `.note-box` class. In short, if you want each item to follow the flexbox layout, you need to make sure the items do not have `position: absolute`, or  `position: fixed`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have absolute positioning on the `note-box` class, all the items are going to get rendered on top of each other. You will want to remove all of your absolute positioning (`position: absolute; left: 22.09%; right: 65.94%; top: 26.58%; bottom: 54.99%;`) to let flexbox arrange your items.

Comment: how would i use flex box to arrange it in the way it was before?

Comment: How were you trying to arrange it? Do you have a picture or example? This article has a pretty good guide on how to use flexbox btw: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/